# pagination suffix doesn't work on previous links

Tags: codeigniter

hi this in my pagination code

```
$config['base_url']    = base_url().'cp/orders/';
$config['suffix'] = '?'.http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$config['total_rows']  = $count_all;
$config['per_page']    = 20 ;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

so in the first page it works fine when i click on page2 it goes to

```
http://mysite.com/cp/orders/20?sort=id&adc=desc
```

but in the second page if i click on page one or previous page ( < ) it goes to

```
http://mysite.com/cp/orders/20
```

this

```
$config['suffix'] = '?'.http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");
```

doesn't work in the previous  links!

Comment: it goes back to the main config on `per_page`, did you try adding the same suffix on the `per_page` also?

Comment: @tomexsans i'm not sure what you mean by adding suffix in `per_page` , but i've put to suffix after `$config['per_page']    = 20 ;` but it doesn't change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found and fixed a bug that was related to the first page links being inconsistent with the rest of the page links. I'd suggest extending the Pagination library with the current version in the Github repo until CodeIgniter 3.0 is released, at which point it will be built-in and you can remove your extended lib.

The new version also has a config option called `reuse_query_string`, which when set to `TRUE` will keep any existing query strings. So if they are already present when you reach the page, you do not need to worry about specifying them as a suffix.

```
$config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;
```

Current library file: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Pagination.php
Related pull request with info: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/2199

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `first_url` as following if you don't want to change the library:

```
$config['first_url'] = $config['base_url'] . $config['suffix'];
```